# search for a variable in a string in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a string given below:

```
string1 = "Hello there, my name is Jack.
Hello there, my name is Jack.
Hello there, my name is Jack."
```

I'm taking the following input from the string:

```
read string2
```

I want to check whether the string2(which is a variable) is present in string1.

I tried running the below command:

```
output=$(echo $string1 | grep -o "$string2")
echo $output
```

eg: Let string2="name"
The output is empty when I'm running this command.
Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the cause of the problem but you should not put a whitespace before and after the `=` character when assigning `string1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

string1="Hello there, my name is Jack"
string2="name"

if [[ $string1 == *"$string2"* ]]; then
    echo "$string2 found"
else
    echo "$string2 not found"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate method with POSIX-shell grammar:

```bash
string1='Hello there, my name is Jack'
string2='name'

case "$string1" in
  *"$string2"*) printf '%s found\n' "$string2";;
  *) printf '%s not found\n' "$string2";;
esac
```